# Python: Instantiate a class from strings in file with arguments

Tags: python-3.x, instantiation

I have several classes imported on a code but I need to instantiate only those classes that are listed on a text file. So I have something like this

```
from module1 import c1
from module2 import c2
...
```

and in the text file I have a list of only those classes I want to instantiate like

```
c1()
c2(True)
...
```

so I want to read the file lines to a list (classes) and do something like

```
for i in classes:
    classes_list.append(i)
```

so that each element of the list is an instantiated class. I tried doing this based on other solutions I found here

```
for i in classes:
    classes_list.append(globals()[i])
```

but I always get this error

```
KeyError: 'c1()'
```

or

```
KeyError: 'c2(True)'
```

Any ideas how something like this could be possible?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) instead of this weird text format?

Comment: Not really, anything that works is fine by me. The only requirement is that the class list needs to be read from a text file since other people will be defining which classes they want to use and I have no way of knowing which ones they'll choose. Also people could want c2 with True or False as argument and I also have no way to know

Comment: How complex can these lines get? `c2(True)` okay I can have True/False. Can I have multiple parameters? Integers? How about math (e.g., `c2(1+3)`)? You are defining  a mini-language here and that can get difficult. You could do `eval(line)` for each line in the file so the user can add full python expressions like calling multiple functions `c2(c1())`.

Comment: Some of them have strings as arguments too. Some could have numbers in the future I guess. All of them have maximum one argument but could also be more in the future so maybe I need a better solution...

Comment: I think eval is working. Thanks @tdelaney

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are implementing a mini-language that expresses how to call certain functions. This can get difficult, but it turns out python already implements its own mini language with the `eval` function. With `eval`, python will compile and execute python expressions.

This is considered risky for stuff coming from anonymous and potentially malicious users on the network but may be a reasonable solution for people who have some level of trust. For instance, if the people writing these files are in your organization and could mess with you a thousand ways anyway, you may be able to trust them with this. I implemented a system were people could write fragments of test code and my system would wrap it all up and turn it into a test suite. No problem because those folks already had complete access to the systems under test.

**module1.py**

```
def c1(p=1):
    return p

def c2(p=1):
    return p

def c3(p=1):
    return p
```

**test.py**

```
import module1

my_globals = {
    'c1': module1.c1, 
    'c2': module1.c2,
    'c3': module1.c3,
}

test = ["c1()",
    "c2(p=c1())",
    "c3('i am a string')",
    "c1(100)"]


for line in test:
    print(line.strip() + ':', eval(line, my_globals))
```

**result**

```
c1(): 1
c2(p=c1()): 1
c3('i am a string'): i am a string
c1(100): 100
```